# Update database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I use `SetInitializer` to only update the database? I don't want to drop and recreate it, because I've added only a column:

```
Database.SetInitializer<myDbContext>( /* Here */ );
```

Comment: You should to add migrations to it!

Comment: @cura I'm using EF5

Comment: @user1187282 EF5 can still use migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use [`DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) since your model classes (entity classes) have been changed.

> You can also create your own [custom initializer](http://Custom%20DB%20Initializer), if the above do
> not satisfy your requirements or you want to do some other process
> that initializes the database using the above initializer.

That should be something like this:

```
public class YourCustomInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(YourDBContext context)
    {
        // sample data to be written or updated to the DB
    }
}
```

It is worth mentioning, you can simply add your new column to your entity, then use [add-migration and update-database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) commands. You need to run these commands in the PackageManagerConsole.

Comment: how can i add a column using the DbContext  ?

Comment: @user1187282 Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thought OP didn't want to drop and create database?!